# Input byte array has incorrect ending byte at 40

Tags: java, base64, illegalargumentexception

I have a string that is base64 encoded. It looks like this:

```
eyJibGExIjoiYmxhMSIsImJsYTIiOiJibGEyIn0=
```

Any online tool can decode this to the proper string which is `{"bla1":"bla1","bla2":"bla2"}`. However, my Java implementation fails:

```
import java.util.Base64;
System.out.println("payload = " + payload);
String json = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(payload));
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
payload = eyJibGExIjoiYmxhMSIsImJsYTIiOiJibGEyIn0=
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input byte array has incorrect ending byte at 40
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://ideone.com/z07TWN), an extra char on the end of the string would raise that exact exception ...

Comment: But from where are you getting the coded string? how do you pass it to the payload variable?, because as you say, it works... I've just tested it with Java 8 and no problems.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Okay, I found out. The original String is encoded on an Android device using `android.util.Base64` by `Base64.encodeToString(json.getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.DEFAULT);`. It uses `android.util.Base64.DEFAULT` encoding scheme.

Then on the server side when using `java.util.Base64` this has to be decoded with `Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(payload)` *not* with `Base64.getDecoder().decode(payload)`

Comment: Do you know if there is the same problem the other way around? I mean, can we have an error if an Android device tries to read a String encoded by a Java implementation?

Comment: I had this problem moving from Mac (where `Base64.getDecoder` worked) to a Windows platform.  Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 15):

I was trying to use the strings from the args. I found that if I use `arg[0].trim()` that it made it work. eg

```
Base64.getDecoder().decode(arg[0].trim());
```

I guess there's some sort of whitespace that gets it messed up.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe too late, but I also had this problem.

By default, the Android Base64 util adds a newline character to the end of the encoded string.
The Base64.NO_WRAP flag tells the util to create the encoded string without the newline character.

Your android app should encode `src` something like this:

```
String encode = Base64.encodeToString(src.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

Comment: PHP 8 did the same thing to me; imagine my surprise, older versions of PHP didn't pad/wrap like that IIRC