# base64 encoding outputs incorrect ending byte

Tags: python, dictionary, encoding, base64

One mobile app I am trying to scrape accepts b64 encoded requests. I tried the following:

```
post_data = {
"id": iv, 
"command": "queryDoc",
 "params": {
     "pageNum": "1", 
     "sortFields": "s50:desc", 
     "ciphertext": make_ciphertext(), 
     "devid": "d607f6d3de0f4f68b44aae416592f559", 
     "devtype": "1", 
     "pageSize": "20", 
     "queryCondition": [{"key":"s21","value":"2020"}]
     }
}

post_data_encoded = base64.b64encode(json.dumps(post_data).encode())
print (post_data_encoded)

with requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=post_data_encoded) as req:
    print (req.json())
```

However, the response reads:

```
{
    "data": {},
    "ret": {
        "code": 9,
        "msg": "Input byte array has incorrect ending byte at 900"
    }
}
```

I tried to decode the real requests from my phone browser, and it yielded a dictionary with all the same parameters. What could be going wrong here?

I did look at a similar issue here: [Input byte array has incorrect ending byte at 40](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35292836/input-byte-array-has-incorrect-ending-byte-at-40)

Could it be that b64encode in Python outputs differently than `java.util.Base64`? I appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Can you show a link to the documentation of that API you are using?

Comment: I suspect that you should use `json.dumps(post_data)`, not `str(post_data)`.

Comment: `headers=headers` are you setting content type and encoding?

Comment: I tried `json.dumps(post_data)`, but the result is the same.

Comment: Just added the full code and request URL. Thanks for looking into this!

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. Base64 works as expected. The problem is my request. Instead of posting `post_data_encoded` as `data` in the request, I created a dictionary `{'request':post_data_encoded}` and the result came out as expected.